# Possible to insert a row based on subquery?

Tags: prisma

I have tables `Task`, `TaskType`, `DefaultTaskType`. Each Task has a single TaskType. A row in DefaultTaskType indicates the default type a new Task should have, and DefaultTaskType only ever holds one row.

The application will have some TaskTypes seeded in the database initially, with one of them being the default.

In Prisma, how would you create a new Task with the default TaskType in one database trip like this:

`INSERT INTO Task (label, taskTypeId) SELECT 'my label', taskTypeId FROM TaskType tt INNER JOIN DefaultTaskType dtt WHERE tt.id = dtt.taskTypeId`

Schema

```
model TaskType {
  id                String    @id @default(cuid())
  displayOrder      Int       @unique
  label             String
  description       String?
  createdAt         DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt         DateTime  @updatedAt
  tasks             Task[]
  defaultTaskType   DefaultTaskType?
}

model DefaultTaskType {
  id          Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  taskTypeId  String @unique
  type        TaskType @relation(fields: [taskTypeId], references: [id])
}

model Task {
  id          String    @id @default(cuid())
  label       String
  description String?
  taskTypeId  String
  type        TaskType @relation(fields: [taskTypeId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

Outside of executing a raw query, it seems Prisma doesn't support a subquery like this? I can only think of one trip to query for the default TaskType then perform the create accordingly.

Thank you for any clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prisma does not provide a built-in way to perform a subquery like the one you described in your question, where you insert a new Task with the default TaskType in one database trip. To perform it in one database trip, you would need to use [raw queries](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access)

However, you can accomplish this in two steps using Prisma:

1. You can use the Prisma client to query the DefaultTaskType to get the taskTypeId of the default TaskType:

```js
const defaultTaskType = await prisma.defaultTaskType.findOne();
const taskTypeId = defaultTaskType.taskTypeId;
```

2. Once you have the taskTypeId, you can use it to create a new Task with that TaskType:

```js
const newTask = await prisma.task.create({
  data: {
    label: 'my label',
    type: {
      connect: {
        id: taskTypeId
      }
    }
  }
});
```

In this way you will use only one database call to find the default TaskType and then another one to add the task with this information.